# Enforce Drive API for Android to work online mode only

Tags: android, google-play-services, google-drive-android-api

Recently, I just manage to migrate Drive API related code from **Google APIs Client Library for Java** to **Google Play services client library**

*The following code is search a file in appdata folder, then download it as temp file.*

```
private static GoogleCloudFile searchFromGoogleDrive(GoogleApiClient googleApiClient, HandleStatusable h, PublishProgressable p) {
    DriveFolder driveFolder = Drive.DriveApi.getAppFolder(googleApiClient);

    final String titleName = ("my-title");
    Query query = new Query.Builder()
            .addFilter(Filters.and(
                Filters.contains(SearchableField.TITLE, titleName),
                Filters.eq(SearchableField.TRASHED, false)
            ))
            .build();

    DriveApi.MetadataBufferResult metadataBufferResult = driveFolder.queryChildren(googleApiClient, query).await();

    if (metadataBufferResult == null) {
        return null;
    }

    Status status = metadataBufferResult.getStatus();

    if (!status.isSuccess()) {
        h.handleStatus(status);
        return null;
    }

    MetadataBuffer metadataBuffer = null;
    boolean needToReleaseMetadataBuffer = true;

    try {
        metadataBuffer = metadataBufferResult.getMetadataBuffer();
        if (metadataBuffer != null ) {
            long checksum = 0;
            long date = 0;
            int version = 0;
            Metadata metadata = null;

            for (Metadata md : metadataBuffer) {
                if (p.isCancelled()) {
                    return null;
                }

                if (md == null || !md.isDataValid()) {
                    continue;
                }

                final String title = md.getTitle();

                // ...

                metadata = md;

                break;

            }   // for

            if (metadata != null) {
                // Caller will be responsible to release the resource. If release too early,
                // metadata will not readable.
                needToReleaseMetadataBuffer = false;
                return GoogleCloudFile.newInstance(metadataBuffer, metadata, checksum, date, version);
            }
        }   // if
    } finally {
        if (needToReleaseMetadataBuffer) {
            if (metadataBuffer != null) {
                metadataBuffer.release();
            }
        }
    }

    return null;
}

public static CloudFile loadFromGoogleDrive(GoogleApiClient googleApiClient, HandleStatusable h, PublishProgressable p) {
    final java.io.File directory = ...

    GoogleCloudFile googleCloudFile = searchFromGoogleDrive(googleApiClient, h, p);

    if (googleCloudFile == null) {
        return null;
    }

    try {
        DriveFile driveFile = googleCloudFile.metadata.getDriveId().asDriveFile();
        DriveApi.DriveContentsResult driveContentsResult = driveFile.open(googleApiClient, DriveFile.MODE_READ_ONLY, null).await();

        if (driveContentsResult == null) {
            return null;
        }

        Status status = driveContentsResult.getStatus();
        if (!status.isSuccess()) {
            h.handleStatus(status);
            return null;
        }

        final long checksum = googleCloudFile.checksum;
        final long date = googleCloudFile.date;
        final int version = googleCloudFile.version;

        p.publishProgress(MyApplication.instance().getString(R.string.downloading));

        final DriveContents driveContents = driveContentsResult.getDriveContents();

        InputStream inputStream = null;
        java.io.File outputFile = null;
        OutputStream outputStream = null;

        try {
            inputStream = driveContents.getInputStream();
            outputFile = java.io.File.createTempFile("me", ".zip", directory);
            outputFile.deleteOnExit();
            outputStream = new FileOutputStream(outputFile);

            int read = 0;
            byte[] bytes = new byte[1024];

            while ((read = inputStream.read(bytes)) != -1) {
                outputStream.write(bytes, 0, read);
            }
        } catch (IOException ex) {
            Log.e(TAG, "", ex);
        } finally {
            org.yccheok.file.Utils.close(outputStream);
            org.yccheok.file.Utils.close(inputStream);
            driveContents.discard(googleApiClient);
        }

        if (outputFile == null) {
            return null;
        }

        return CloudFile.newInstance(outputFile, checksum, date, version);
    } finally {
        googleCloudFile.metadataBuffer.release();
    }
}
```

Previously, when I'm using **Google APIs Client Library for Java**, the similar code will just throw exception, if there's no internet connection.

*However, when I'm using **Google Play services client library**, the above code still work successfully, even though I have my device in airplane mode, and turn off wifi.*

It seems that Drive API from **Google Play services client library**, is able to read the offline file, when there's no internet connection.

Is there any way, to enforce the above code will fail, when there is no internet connection? As, I want to avoid risk of having my users to download outdated cloud file.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's no way to force a failure as you ask.

What you can do is request a sync with the server before your query: https://developers.google.com/android/reference/com/google/android/gms/drive/DriveApi.html#requestSync(com.google.android.gms.common.api.GoogleApiClient)

If there's no connection, the sync will fail with a network error.

Comment: Problem with requestSync is that, I can easy hit "request rate limit exceeded." I merely make the 2nd request 10s after the first. Any idea what is the hard limit for request rate? 10 seconds after the 1st call doesn't seem like an unreasonable rate to me.

Comment: Currently, the limit is 1 minute, with a burst size of 5 requests.
So after more than 5 minutes without requesting sync you should be able to request up to 5 syncs in succession.
Requesting a sync every 10s seems a bit too much though.

Comment: Hi Anatoli, can you kindly explain what does it mean by "burst size of 5"? Does it mean that if I make 1st request at 0th min, 2nd request at 1st min, ... I will not make 6th request at 5th min? I need to cool down for 5 minutes, only I can make 6th request?

Comment: You don't need to cool down as long as your requests frequency is not greater than 1 per minute.
In your example, 6th request at 5th minute will work fine, so will the 7th request at 6th minute and so on.

Comment: Essentially, you need to cool down for 1 minute before making one request. But you can cool down for longer to make more requests.
After 2 minutes of cooling - you'll be able to make 2 requests immediately one after the other.
After 3 minutes of cooling - 3 immediate requests.
After 4 - 4, after 5 - 5.
After more than 5 minutes of cooling you'll only be able to make 5 immediate requests.

(That's why the burst size is 5). Hope this is helpful.

Comment: Thanks for the info. Is this info published anywhere, as I can't find them. Or, are you Googler who works on this? :)

Comment: Is it possible to update your answer with the current method of determining the rate limit?  The current method seems to be much less forgiving than the one described in the comment on 2016-01-19, and still seems to not be documented anywhere.

Comment: I believe there were no changes in the rate limit. Are you experiencing a limit more aggressive than this?

Comment: It's impossible to tell for sure.  I only know that I still run into it inconsistently, when an app waits at least 65 seconds between attempts.  It's like there's some other unknown variable, so I might have to create a special app that is better suited for testing it.

It would be great if the rate limit could be described in the official API documentation at https://developers.google.com/android/reference/com/google/android/gms/drive/DriveClient#requestSync%28%29

Your comments here are really appreciated, but they're still the only info I can find out about it.

Comment: Unfortunately, I'm not working on this product any more, but I will pass the request to update the documentation.