# Check requestSync result status with Tasks Drive API

Tags: android, google-drive-api, google-drive-android-api

With the previous API (using `PendingResult`), I could do something like:

```
Drive.DriveApi.requestSync(mGoogleApiClient).setResultCallback(new ResultCallback<Status>() {
          @Override
          public void onResult(@NonNull Status status) {
            if (status.getStatusCode() == DRIVE_RATE_LIMIT_EXCEEDED) {
              //Here I know Drive rate limit was exceeded.
            }
          }
        });
```

How can I accomplish the same with the new `Tasks`API?

For what I read in the [documentation](https://developers.google.com/android/reference/com/google/android/gms/drive/DriveClient.html?#requestSync()):

> If the request has been rate-limited, the operation will fail with the
>   DRIVE_RATE_LIMIT_EXCEEDED status

But how do I check the status of `Task<Void> requestSync`?

This is as far as I've got:

```
Task<Void> checkSync = myDriveClient.requestSync();
checkSync.addOnCompleteListener(new OnCompleteListener<Void>() {
    @Override
        public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<Void> task) {
            //how do I check the status here?
        }
});
```

Comment: I've read it from this [SO post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/34802223) that the sync will fail with a network error if there's no connection. So, to support offline cases, try implementing a sync engine that runs in the background to merge upstream and downstream changes as discussed [here](https://developers.google.com/drive/android/files).

Comment: @Teyam I'm not looking for offline cases, I just want to know how to read the status that supposedly `requestSync` returns or updates.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I had the same problem. In fact it is the Exception of the onFailureListener.
But I needed to cast it to an ApiException.

```
Task<Void> checkSync = Drive.getDriveClient(getContext(), mGoogleSignInAccount).requestSync();
    checkSync.addOnCompleteListener(new OnCompleteListener<Void>() {
        @Override
        public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<Void> task) {
            //how do I check the status here?
        }
    }).addOnFailureListener(new OnFailureListener() {
        @Override
        public void onFailure(@NonNull Exception e) {
            ApiException apiException = (ApiException) e;
            if (DriveStatusCodes.DRIVE_RATE_LIMIT_EXCEEDED == apiException.getStatusCode()) {
                //Here I know Drive rate limit was exceeded.
            }
        }
    });
```

Hope it helps.

Answer (score 0):

You can check status of requestSync by calling task.isSuccessful() . It appeared, that if DRIVE_RATE_LIMIT_EXCEEDED happens addOnCompleteListener will be called anyway at first.

```
myDriveClient.requestSync()
.addOnCompleteListener(task -> {
        if (task.isSuccessful()) {
            Log.i(TAG, "requestSync success");
        } else {
            Log.i(TAG, "requestSync not successful");
        }
    })
    .addOnFailureListener(e -> {
        Log.i(TAG, "requestSync failure");
    });
```